# Custom mail send from joomla

Tags: joomla, newsletter

Hi I just looking for any extension or custom code for joomla module to subscribe for newsletter. It's also ok for me if the mail is going to admin mail address.

I am using joomla 1.5 version and have a form in sidebar for subscribing newsletter.Site is http://www.onlinecasinosouthafrica.co.za/. just want to send mail from this form to admin email address.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need a whole newsletter solution or just send an email to admin address ?

Comment: I just want to send mail to admin address

Answer (score 1):

Here are some useful modules and components you find useful.

- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/mailing-a-distribution-lists/6414
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/10341
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/13760
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/13760
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/8451
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/9771
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/11585
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/9361
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/964
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/9964
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/newsletter/5063
- http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/content-sharing/mailing-a-newsletter-bridges
- http://codecanyon.net/item/simple-joomla-newsletter-extension/159767

Good luck..